How to combine type-heterogenous data with type-generic algoritms in iteration?
I wrote some ODE Solvers in rust that are generic. I hope to gain two things by the generics: efficient code generation and compile time checks. I then have a heterogenous collection of initial value problems (IVPs) that I want to process with these solvers. The different IVPs use different kinds of floats, have vectors with diffent shapes etc. I now want to benchmark my solvers on this heterogenous set of IVPs.
I have after some edts, rewrites etc boiled down the code to an example code base of ca 200 lines. Instead of solving ODEs it does matrix multiplication, since that takes fewer lines of code. The general problem of a type generic algorithm is the same. See below or in the playground: rust playground
I have decided to wrap all problem specifications in enums so that I can have a collection to iterate over. The problem set has a type_id method to introspect the generic type parameters relevant for this problem. Then, there is a hashtable with instantiations of the generic algorithms for that specific type id.
The solution technically works, but it is fragile. I expect there to be a better solution in Rust on how to do this. MAybe some unsafe casting, macro magic or something?!
The problems with the current approach:

I need to add enum variants depending on the problems I use.
I need to add variants both in the Solver and Problem enums, and there is no compile time check I have all instantiations I will need.
I need to add instances in the HashMap for each enum, and there is no compile time check I have all instantiations I will need.
The implementation of Problem::type_id has a manual mapping from the name of the enum variant to a type id. That is error prone.

Is there a way to work around these problems by using some other Rust mechanism to allow iteration over the problem set and apply all algorithms on the problems, while still retaining monomorphization and generics?
use nalgebra as na; // 0.32.3
#[allow(non_camel_case_types,non_snake_case)]


mod bench_utils{
    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    use nalgebra as na;
    /// Generic problem description
    /// They all represent two matrices A and B that needs to be multiplied
    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub struct GenProb<T,D>
    where
    D: na::Dim,
    na::DefaultAllocator: na::allocator::Allocator<T, na::Const<3>, D>
     + na::allocator::Allocator<T, D,na::Const<3>> 
    {
        pub name: String,
        pub A: na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,D>,
        pub B: na::OMatrix<T,D,na::Const<3>>
    }
    
    /// Generic solver description
    /// A matrix multiplication algorithm
    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub struct GenSolv<T,D>
    where 
    T: na::Scalar,
    D: na::Dim,
    na::DefaultAllocator: na::allocator::Allocator<T, na::Const<3>, D>
     + na::allocator::Allocator<T, D,na::Const<3>> 
    {
        pub name: String,
        pub solver: fn(na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,D>,na::OMatrix<T,D,na::Const<3>>) -> na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,na::Const<3>>
    }
    
    /// Instantiate all thinkable GenProb that you might need
    pub enum Problem {
        P_1_64(GenProb<f64,na::Const<1>>),
        P_1_32(GenProb<f32,na::Const<1>>),
        P_5_64(GenProb<f64,na::Const<5>>),
        P_5_32(GenProb<f32,na::Const<5>>),
        P_dyn_64(GenProb<f64,na::Dyn>),
        P_dyn_32(GenProb<f32,na::Dyn>),
    }
    impl Problem {
        pub fn type_id(&self) -> std::any::TypeId {
            match self {
                Problem::P_1_64(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Const<1>>>(),
                Problem::P_1_32(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Const<1>>>(),
                Problem::P_5_64(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Const<5>>>(),
                Problem::P_5_32(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Const<5>>>(),
                Problem::P_dyn_64(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Dyn>>(),
                Problem::P_dyn_32(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Dyn>>(),
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// Instantiate all thinkable GenProb that you might need
    pub enum Solver {
        S_1_64(GenSolv<f64,na::Const<1>>),
        S_1_32(GenSolv<f32,na::Const<1>>),
        S_5_64(GenSolv<f64,na::Const<5>>),
        S_5_32(GenSolv<f32,na::Const<5>>),
        S_dyn_64(GenSolv<f64,na::Dyn>),
        S_dyn_32(GenSolv<f32,na::Dyn>),
    }
    
    pub fn process<T,D>(prob:GenProb<T,D>,solv:GenSolv<T,D>) where
    D: na::Dim,
    T: na::RealField,
    na::DefaultAllocator: na::allocator::Allocator<T, na::Const<3>, D>
     + na::allocator::Allocator<T, D,na::Const<3>>,
    {
        let now = std::time::Instant::now();
        let _C = (solv.solver)(prob.A,prob.B);
        let elapsed = now.elapsed();
        println!("Running {:10} on {:15} took {:?} seconds",solv.name,prob.name,elapsed)
    }
}

mod multipliers{
    //! A module containing matrix multiplication methods
    
    use nalgebra as na;
    use nalgebra; // 0.32.5

    /// The built in matrix multiply
    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    pub fn na_star<T,D>(
        A: na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,D>,
        B: na::OMatrix<T,D,na::Const<3>>
    ) -> na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,na::Const<3>>
    where
    T: na::RealField,
    D: na::Dim,
    na::DefaultAllocator: na::allocator::Allocator<T, na::Const<3>, D>
     + na::allocator::Allocator<T, D,na::Const<3>> {
            A * B
    }
    
    /// An alternative implementation
    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    pub fn manual<T,D>(
        A: na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,D>,
        B: na::OMatrix<T,D,na::Const<3>>
    ) -> na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,na::Const<3>>
    where
    T: na::RealField + std::iter::Sum + Copy,
    D: na::Dim,
    na::DefaultAllocator: na::allocator::Allocator<T, na::Const<3>, D>
     + na::allocator::Allocator<T, D,na::Const<3>> {
        let mut out = vec![];
        for r in 0..3 {
            for c in 0..3 {
                out.push(
                    A.row(r).iter().zip(B.column(c).iter()).map(|(&a,&b)| a*b).sum()
                )
            }
        }
        na::Matrix3::from_vec(out)
    }
}

use bench_utils::*;

pub fn main() {

    let problems = vec![
        Problem::P_1_64(GenProb{name:"1 64 static".into(), A: na::Matrix3x1::new(0.0, 1.0, 2.0),B: na::Matrix1x3::new(2.0, 1.0, 0.0)}),
        Problem::P_5_64(GenProb{name:"5 64 static".into(), A: na::Matrix3x5::new(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0),B: na::Matrix5x3::new(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0)}),
        Problem::P_1_32(GenProb{name:"1 32 static".into(), A: na::Matrix3x1::new(0.0, 1.0, 2.0),B: na::Matrix1x3::new(2.0, 1.0, 0.0)}),
        Problem::P_5_32(GenProb{name:"5 32 static".into(), A: na::Matrix3x5::new(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0),B: na::Matrix5x3::new(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0)}),
        Problem::P_dyn_64(GenProb{name:"1 64 dyn".into(), A: na::Matrix::<f64,na::Const<3>,na::Dyn,_>::from_vec(vec![0.0,1.0,2.0]), B: na::Matrix::<f64,na::Dyn,na::Const<3>,_>::from_vec(vec![0.0,1.0,2.0]) }),
        Problem::P_dyn_64(GenProb{name:"5 64 dyn".into(), A: na::Matrix::<f64,na::Const<3>,na::Dyn,_>::from_vec(vec![1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]), B: na::Matrix::<f64,na::Dyn,na::Const<3>,_>::from_vec(vec![1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]) }),
        Problem::P_dyn_32(GenProb{name:"1 32 dyn".into(), A: na::Matrix::<_,na::Const<3>,na::Dyn,_>::from_vec(vec![0.0,1.0,2.0]), B: na::Matrix::<_,na::Dyn,na::Const<3>,_>::from_vec(vec![0.0,1.0,2.0]) }),
        Problem::P_dyn_32(GenProb{name:"5 32 dyn".into(), A: na::Matrix::<_,na::Const<3>,na::Dyn,_>::from_vec(vec![1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]), B: na::Matrix::<_,na::Dyn,na::Const<3>,_>::from_vec(vec![1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]) }),
        ];
    let solvers: std::collections::HashMap<_, Vec<_>> = std::collections::HashMap::from([
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Const<1>>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_1_64(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_1_64(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Const<5>>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_5_64(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_5_64(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Dyn>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_dyn_64(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_dyn_64(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Const<1>>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_1_32(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_1_32(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Const<5>>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_5_32(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_5_32(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Dyn>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_dyn_32(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_dyn_32(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        
    ]);
    for prob in &problems{ 
        let id = prob.type_id();
        for solv in &solvers[&id] {
            match (prob,solv) {
                ( Problem::P_1_64(p), Solver::S_1_64(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                ( Problem::P_5_64(p), Solver::S_5_64(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                ( Problem::P_dyn_64(p), Solver::S_dyn_64(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                ( Problem::P_1_32(p), Solver::S_1_32(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                ( Problem::P_5_32(p), Solver::S_5_32(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                ( Problem::P_dyn_32(p), Solver::S_dyn_32(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                _ => eprintln!("This problem/solver pair is not compatible")
            }
        }
    }
}


We need to know more about your real code. For this example case, what I would do is to bundle the data with the operation on it in a struct that implements a trait. But I don't know if that's good for your real case.
